# Can one define a function to tell whether an element was constructed from a given type constructor?

Tags: types, f#, discriminated-union

I'm working in F#, and have a type T which is a discriminated union of several things:

```
type T =
  | A of string * int
  | B of int
  | C
```

If I have a T list, I may want to pull out the things that were constructed using A. It's easy to pattern match like this:

```
myList
|> List.filter (fun x -> match x with | A(_,_) -> true | _ -> false)
```

The embedded match is a bit verbose, and there's a minor maintenance hassle in keeping the number of underscores in sync with the definition of A. I'd really like a function like this:

```
let constructedFrom (type constructor) (t : T) : bool = something

myList
|> List.filter (constructedFrom A)
```

Is there a way to define this 'constructedFrom' function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The embedded match is a bit verbose, and there's a minor maintenance hassle in keeping the number of underscores in sync with the definition of A.

You can save a few keystrokes using `function` keyword. You can also use `_` as a pattern of ignoring everything (it doesn't mean you have to bind to a single value).

```
myList
|> List.filter (function A _  -> true | _ -> false)
```

In general, if you repeatedly write functions as above, you should define a few [active patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd233248.aspx), one for each case:

```
let (|ACase|_|) = function 
    | A _ as x -> Some x 
    | _ -> None

myList |> List.choose (|ACase|_|)
```

> Is there a way to define this 'constructedFrom' function?

There's no idiomatic way to do so. I think active patterns can remedy the problem most of time.

Comment: Thanks for this response. I'll likely use both the 'function' keyword and the use of '_' to ignore all arguments in the future.

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify the `match` in your `List.filter` by using `function` instead of `fun`. `function` = `fun x -> match x with`.

```
myList
|> List.filter (function A(_,_) -> true | _ -> false)
```

I don't think there's a way (or at least a *good* way) to define your `constructedFrom` function.

Comment: Thanks for this. I didn't know about 'function' before your answer.